# visual studio: how to catch non-matching number of dummy/formal argument in a big old code without interfaces

Tags: visual-studio-2010, fortran

I am using Visual Studio on Windows together with Intel(R) Visual Fortran Composer XE 2011.  I have a big old code with thousands of subroutines. I did some substantial changes adding other hundreds of subroutines and now I am having some access violation errors, the which reason that I have hard time to identify. It is likely due to non-matching number of dummy/formal argument, since it happened to me before and the symptoms were the same and it took me 2 days to figure out where the problem was. Is there an add-on to Visual Studio to catch this kind of error? The programming style is fortran 77 and in no case I am required to provide explicit interfaces as for 90 standard. I know explicit interface would help but adding them for all the code would be days of work.
thanks
A.

Comment: What language are you working in? Visual Studio has modules for C++, C#, VB.Net and F#, but AFAIK it doesn't support Fortran. If you *are* working in Fortran, what plug-in are you using?

Comment: It s a solution with plenty of C++ and Fortran projects. I dont understand what do you mean for plug-in? Anyways the error is: Unhandled exception at 0x778915de (ntdll.dll) in d_hydro.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x000024b0. It would nice to have a tool in visual studio to catch it.

Comment: I mean that Visual Studio, as you get it from Microsoft, doesn't support Fortran. So the question is, what Fortran compiler do you use (Intel's?) and how is it integrated into VS? That would be a good starting point for people to help. Also, you should tag questions about Fortran with the fortran tag, so that people who actually know Fortran (I don't) can find the question more easily.

Comment: And even without knowing Fortran, simply from the fact that you already lost 2 days to such a problem once, I'm pretty sure that adding function declarations that allow error checking would be worth it.

Comment: I use Intel(R) Visual Fortran Composer XE 2011. Added on the question.thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't have VS on this machine so can't check exactly which Properties page you need to find, but there is an option, probably under Diagnostics, to have the compiler check procedure calls at compile time.  On the command-line the compiler option is `/warn:interfaces` and it causes the compiler to check implicit interfaces. No plug-in is necessary, the Intel Fortran compiler incorporates the necessary functionality.